# Sorting in SQl query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my table that stores max 2 characters. For eg. **B,AK,SE** etc.

Suppose I have two rows in that table, one having **'K'** and other having **'BA'** as a value.

Requirement in my project is such that I have to get the maximum value from the table based on the no. of characters in case there is a difference in the length. In this case, maximum value will be **'BA'** not **'K'**.

But when I use '**order by column desc**' with **rownum = 1** in my query, **'K'** is returned as rownum 0th value.

If I have values **'D','BA','AK','C'** then output should be **'BA','AK','C','D'**
Just want to know if there is any way I can fulfill my requirement?

Comment: what do you mean by `rownum = 0`? don't you mean `rownum = 1`?

Comment: Sorry typo mistake it's rownum=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way could be:

```
ORDER BY length(<col_name>) desc
```

UPDATE - if you need to order by the value also, you can do:

```
ORDER BY length(<col_name>) desc, <col_name> desc
```

Comment: but by doing so, I will not be able to sort single/double character values. For eg. 1) 'F' and 'H' 2) 'DF' and 'HG'

Comment: edited my explanation little bit to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
select * from (
  select row_number() over(order by length(col_name) desc, col_name desc) rn, col_name
  from tab_name
) where rn = 1
```